# Gridview with flexible height

Tags: asp.net, css, gridview

I have a gridview which has fixed height of 450 px, which covers upto 15 rows. I have a vertical scrollbar inside the grid to scroll. I want that if the number of records are less than 8 then the height of the gridview must be automatically reduced. But the height should not exceed 450 px for more records. Please help!

Comment: Thank you guys its working fine now. I had to set *max height: 450 px* in the div. And *height:auto* in the grid view CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping the gridview with container div and apply the CSS to it.

CSS

```
<style type="text/css">
 #grid-view-container
 {
  height:auto;
  overflow:scroll;
  max-height:450px;
 }
</style>
```

In .aspx

```
<div id="grid-view-container">

    <asp:GridView ID="gvSample" runat="server">/GridView>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the css property in style tag

```
height:auto;max-height:450px;
```